mysql delete table join is many times slower than query without index
I have a simple table with less than 1,000 rows.
CREATE TABLE `t_source_category` (
  `id` smallint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `leaf` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` decimal(12,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `1` (`title`,`pid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1066 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

t_source_item_category
CREATE TABLE `t_source_item__category` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18601 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

It is very fast when I use the query, takes 0.129s.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
    SELECT * FROM t_source_category t1 
        LEFT JOIN t_source_item__category t2 ON t2.category_id = t1.id 
    WHERE t2.item_id IS NULL AND t1.leaf = 1;

output:
-> Filter: (t2.item_id is null)  (cost=507334.85 rows=500864) (actual time=96.914..96.914 rows=0 loops=1)
    -> Left hash join (t2.category_id = t1.id)  (cost=507334.85 rows=500864) (actual time=41.850..95.894 rows=12537 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (t1.leaf = 1)  (cost=82.25 rows=405) (actual time=0.046..0.462 rows=685 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on t1  (cost=82.25 rows=810) (actual time=0.041..0.356 rows=811 loops=1)
        -> Hash
            -> Table scan on t2  (cost=16.24 rows=12367) (actual time=0.029..2.984 rows=12546 loops=1)

When I use the delete statement, takes 5.870s:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
    DELETE t1 FROM t_source_category t1 
        LEFT JOIN t_source_item__category t2 ON t2.category_id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.item_id IS NULL AND t1.leaf = 1;

output:
-> Delete from t1 (immediate)
    -> Filter: (t2.item_id is null)  (cost=502073.96 rows=500864) (actual time=5800.754..5800.754 rows=0 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop left join  (cost=502073.96 rows=500864) (actual time=0.100..5799.583 rows=12537 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (t1.leaf = 1)  (cost=82.25 rows=405) (actual time=0.040..2.560 rows=685 loops=1)
                -> Table scan on t1  (cost=82.25 rows=810) (actual time=0.028..2.087 rows=811 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (t2.category_id = t1.id)  (cost=3.09 rows=1237) (actual time=3.329..8.460 rows=18 loops=685)
                -> Table scan on t2  (cost=3.09 rows=12367) (actual time=0.005..7.649 rows=12546 loops=685)

What am I doing wrong?
How to use delete table join statement correctly?

I'm guessing it has to use a different plan because deleting a row might affect something after that. In this case I don't think it does, but it's a missed optimization in the query planner.

Pls, show DDL for  table t_source_item__category.

create index iix_item_category_category on t_source_item__category (category_id);

@ValNik The speed of deletion is improved clearly after adding the index. Could you explain the reason behind this? Like why is the select not affected by the index?

SELECT also affected by index. But performance difference  is big relatively, but the absolute difference is small. I'll try to show it in the answer.

If you compare the execution plans of SELECT and DELETE without an index, you can see that in the SELECT operation, the tables are joined using HASH JOIN. Since the tables are small, this gives high performance.
In the DELETE operation, the tables are joined via Nested loops LEFT JOIN. Moreover, the cycle repeats over the category_item table many times (loops=685).
Since the join is actually near Cartesian, the filtering output is 500,000 rows, which is quite a lot for tables of this size.
I can't say why such a plan is being chosen. There may be constraints and relationships between tables. You didn't provide this part of the data, we can only guess.
We can compare execution plans without an index and with an index.  First, let's compare the SELECT operation.
Let's see the difference between query plans without an index and with an index on my model (https://dbfiddle.uk/9xkvkNId).
SELECT
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
    SELECT * FROM t_source_category t1 
        LEFT JOIN t_source_item__category t2 ON t2.category_id = t1.id 
    WHERE t2.item_id IS NULL AND t1.leaf = 1;

Without index
-> Filter: (t2.item_id is null)  (cost=101241 rows=100000) (actual time=2.32..3.85 rows=506 loops=1)
    -> Left hash join (t2.category_id = t1.id)  (cost=101241 rows=100000) (actual time=2.32..3.71 rows=2135 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (t1.leaf = 1)  (cost=100 rows=500) (actual time=0.076..0.895 rows=1000 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on t1  (cost=100 rows=1000) (actual time=0.0745..0.788 rows=1000 loops=1)
        -> Hash
            -> Table scan on t2  (cost=2.52 rows=2000) (actual time=0.0538..1.59 rows=2000 loops=1)

With index
-> Filter: (t2.item_id is null)  (cost=1545 rows=1156) (actual time=0.0688..24.8 rows=506 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop left join  (cost=1545 rows=1156) (actual time=0.0676..24.6 rows=2135 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (t1.leaf = 1)  (cost=100 rows=500) (actual time=0.044..1.08 rows=1000 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on t1  (cost=100 rows=1000) (actual time=0.0423..0.881 rows=1000 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on t2 using iix_item_category_category (category_id=t1.id)  (cost=0.578 rows=2.31) (actual time=0.0135..0.0151 rows=2 loops=1000)

We can see that cost with index is better, and actual time is worse.
But in any case, these are pretty fast queries.
DELETE
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
    DELETE t1 FROM t_source_category t1 
        LEFT JOIN t_source_item__category t2 ON t2.category_id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.item_id IS NULL AND t1.leaf = 1;

Without index
-> Delete from t1 (immediate)  (cost=100284 rows=100000) (actual time=9394..9394 rows=0 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (t2.item_id is null)  (cost=100284 rows=100000) (actual time=2.2..9394 rows=555 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop left join  (cost=100284 rows=100000) (actual time=2.2..9393 rows=2152 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (t1.leaf = 1)  (cost=102 rows=500) (actual time=0.0313..25.6 rows=1000 loops=1)
                -> Table scan on t1  (cost=102 rows=1000) (actual time=0.0304..24.6 rows=1000 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (t2.category_id = t1.id)  (cost=0.403 rows=200) (actual time=4.34..9.37 rows=2 loops=1000)
                -> Table scan on t2  (cost=0.403 rows=2000) (actual time=0.0735..8.53 rows=2000 loops=1000)

With index
-> Delete from t1 (immediate)  (cost=1545 rows=1156) (actual time=28.7..28.7 rows=0 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (t2.item_id is null)  (cost=1545 rows=1156) (actual time=0.0428..28.6 rows=506 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop left join  (cost=1545 rows=1156) (actual time=0.0422..28.3 rows=2135 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (t1.leaf = 1)  (cost=100 rows=500) (actual time=0.0284..1.85 rows=1000 loops=1)
                -> Table scan on t1  (cost=100 rows=1000) (actual time=0.0274..1.65 rows=1000 loops=1)
            -> Index lookup on t2 using iix_item_category_category (category_id=t1.id)  (cost=0.578 rows=2.31) (actual time=0.0216..0.026 rows=2 loops=1000)

Main difference is Table scan against Index lookup (loops=1000). Performance for this operations on table with 12000 rows is sensitive.

I add t_source_item_category schema, it's very simple, no constraints and no foreign keys.
